# Git add not working

Tags: github

I tried to use `git add eu` and now I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'eu' did not match any files
```

How would I upload my existing Maven project to Github? I've tried many things but couldn't manage to upload it so far.

Comment: And 'eu' is a file?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to commit your whole project?

Comment: @KrishnaPradyumnaMokshagundam folder, I used this guide: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/06/how-to-host-a-maven-artifact-on-github/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `git add .` to stage your whole project.

Comment: now you need to commit -> git commit -m "first commit"

Comment: MBA-10-09:~ me$ open .git<br>
MBA-10-09:~ me$ git add *<br>
git commit -m "Added Importer"

Comment: my bad, "git add ." not "git add *"

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the correct path of your file like this : `git add pathToYourFile.extension`. If you would like to add all files so use

```
git add .
```

Answer (score 0):

To add your entire project, do what the other commenters have suggested.

`git add .`

`git commit -m "Your message."`

To add the project to Github, you first need to create a repository in Github, and then add that newly created repo's URL as a remote on your computer. Then push it up. They give instructions after you create your repository.

[image]

Note that you'll need to manually push up changes in the future with `git push`, unless you have a post commit hook or something set up to automate it.

Comment: The problem is that git add . doesn't do anything. It just leaves a new blank line even without a new "Macbook ~ me $" or something

Comment: Have you tried using `git add --all`? Perhaps there's an issue with your installation of Git. Try that command to see if something happens; otherwise, you may want to consider reinstalling Git.

Comment: Another possibility is that it's just adding a HUGE amount of files. How many files do you have in your repository? If that's the case, you could try ignoring a good portion of the files you don't need to watch, or else just watch a subdirectory. For example, if you're working with Wordpress, you probably just need to watch the theme directory, or whatever director you're working with.

Comment: could it be my old git version? I've installed an old version because I'm using Mac OS X Lion (v10.7.5)

Comment: That's a possibility, I suppose. If your version is too older, perhaps the `git add .` notation won't work. That's why you should try `git add --all` to see if that works.